# What does it mean by "suburban trash"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Joey got nearly bitten by shark while swimming, Actually Families of Dave & Joey are on vacation, so Joey & Dave having dinner together with their families.

> Joey: Dave, I was in a car accident once, okay? And it was really
>   scary, I had nightmares. But when...
>
> Dave: I've been in a car accident, too. Have you ever been bit by a
>   shark?
>
> Joey: I was never bit by a shark. I'm just saying that I understand.
>   My...
>
> Dave: Say it again.
>
> Joey: I was in a car accident.
>
> Dave: No, say the last part.
>
> Joey: I was never bit by a shark.
>
> Dave: That's it! Then you shouldn't talk about it. And I'm not gonna sit
>   here and try to explain myself to a bunch of **black and white suburban
>   trash** who don't know a damn thing about the ocean.

What does it mean by "suburban trash" ?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You provide some context in your question, but when you quote please always give the source, it adds to the context ans it makes easier to give as good as possible answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Trash**:

> [Cambridge Dictionary online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trash)
>   US informal an insulting way of referring to a person or people that you have no respect for.

**White Trash**:

> [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/white_trash)
>   (US, idiomatic, pejorative, ethnic slur) A poorly-educated white person or, collectively, white people of low social status.

The "black and white suburban trash" is a very derogatory offensive way of talking of the black and white people who live in the suburbs.

Comment: +1 But not the 'poor' suburbs: *white trash* does not designate an economic status. A central theme of Southern literature from the 30s to the 60s was the rise of *white trash* to positions of wealth and power.

Answer (score 0):

The term "Suburban Trash" to me means somebody who's high class economically, but low class culturally.

I.E.  The types that can easily throw away $150,000 on a fishing boat and truck combo rather than spending that money on a vacation to another country.